# Inheritance avoiding duplicate member variables

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, parent-child

Base Class:

```
public class BaseClass {
    private Animal animal;

    public BaseClass(Animal animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
        // more code
    }

    public Animal getAnimal() {
        return this.animal;
    }

}
```

Child Class:

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    private Dog dog;

    public BaseClass(Dog dog) {
        super(dog);
        this.dog = dog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dog getAnimal() {
        return this.dog;
    }

}
```

Where `Dog extends Animal`.

In this case, `super(dog);` assigns `dog` to `animal` because of the base class' constructor, so `animal` and `dog` are essentially the same. Is there a way to avoid this or is this the best method of implementing this functionality?

Comment: What are the classes `ChildClass` and `BaseClass` supposed to represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the sort of things that generics were invented for. Something along these lines would work:

```
public class BaseClass<TAnimal extends Animal>
{
    private TAnimal animal;

    public BaseClass(TAnimal animal)
    {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public TAnimal getAnimal()
    {
        return animal;
    }
}
```

At this point, simply using `BaseClass<Dog>` would satisfy the requirements of the above code. But you can still have the subclass:

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass<Dog>
{
    public ChildClass(Dog dog)
    {
        super(dog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Dog extends Animal` you can assign Dog to the `animal` variable:

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {    

    public BaseClass(Dog dog) {
        super(dog);        
    }

    @Override
    public Dog getAnimal() {
        return (Dog) this.animal;
    }

}
```

The functionality of `ChildClass` makes sure that only `Dog` can be assigned and `Dog` is returned again.

As you said `super(dog);` assigns *dog to animal*, but **dog is animal** so there's no problem.

Comment: Just as an FYI The cast is unnecessary because Java supports covariant return types.

Comment: Actually ... I was misreading your version, sorry. You actually do need it if you're returning the `Animal` from the parent class. I was stuck on the OP's code where he also had a local `Dog`. Apologies.

Comment: @BrianRoach You actually got me to look into the Docs! For a few minutes I thought I've been doing it for no reason all these years..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the BaseClass constructor in ChildClass. Your ChildClass should rely on BaseClass to do stuff common to all classes that extend it, and only have code in it to do stuff not in the BaseClass.

For example:

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass
{
   public ChildClass(Dog dog)
   {
      super(dog);
   }

}
```

You don't need to override getAnimal to return Dog, calling getAnimal() on ChildClass will invoke getAnimal() in BaseClass which will return the animal set in BaseClass's constructor - which is dog. Try it out. As it is, this class isn't needed. Everything it does is done by BaseClass.